# TableView: Based on rowName setting variables

Tags: objective-c, tableview

Im gonna do a TableView-layout but depending on the chose I would like to set variables to specific numbers.

Examples:

Choosing "row1" -> Alpha = 1.00

Choosing "row2" -> Alpha = 2.00 & Beta = 3.00
and so on...

As far as I concerns tapping on a row just forward to next view, I want all my rows to be linked to the same View but with different/custom Alpha and Beta.

Tried to search but finding it hard to formulate this in xcode word.

Answer (score 0):

So you are going to a new viewController, when tapping on a row? Than look for your code in

```
tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

Inside that code you will find smth. like that:

```
ViewControllerClass* viewController = [[ViewControllerClass alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController animated: YES];
[viewController release];
```

Just add your custom settings, before pushing:

```
ViewControllerClass* viewController = [[ViewControllerClass alloc] init];

if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    viewController.alpha = ...;
    viewController.beta = ...;
}
else if(indexPath.row == 1)
{
    viewController.alpha = ...;
    viewController.beta = ...;
}
else
{
    viewController.alpha = ...;
    viewController.beta = ...;
}


[self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController animated: YES];
[viewController release];
```

Comment: thanks as easy as that =)
But Im confused of how to declare the Alpha in order to access it.
"Property "Alpha" not found on object type ..."

Comment: ..and btw "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'"

Comment: Cannot figure this out! Shouldn't I have **Table**viewController somewhere ? I'm thinking of one UITableViewController(e.g myTableVC) for the TableView and one UIViewController (e.g myVC) for the viewController I'm directed when tapping a/any row

Comment: you did not write, if youre using ARC. you have to define alpha and beta as propertites in your viewcontrollerclass.

Comment: obvious I'm using ARC since I got the error msg (good or bad?)

Do not know how to define variables as propertites in my viewController.      Tried (1) #Define Alpha in [h] can then use it in [m] (even different [m.files]) but i cannot set Alpha to a number

 (2) declaring a NSSttring, int, float as usual but it dose't show/(show = cannot be used) in [m]

I thought thise part was pretty easy...

Comment: sry what you are looking for is basic programming tutorials.. go ahead and search for `learn objective-c`! perhaps start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html and here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072

Comment: I see your point...Is it possible to ask for a url to a more specific tutorial or example or text

Comment: you should read the basics first. but for a quick overview, perhaps: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000081.php and http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/